# Linker Command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation), Xcode 8, Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8, carthage

I can't get rid of this error!

[image]

I have tried all sorts of things like clearing Derived Data(Preferences->Locations->click gray arrow to open Derived Data folder in Finder->right-click, move to trash), cleaning the project(CMD+Shift+K or Product->Clean), updating carthage and dependencies, checked other answers on StackOverflow (mostly adjustments in Build Settings/Phases), and recloned the app from github, etc.

The same project works on my collaborators computers..

EDIT:
From the current top-rated answer, I was able to debug a little further...I am still not sure how to fix though. It looks like I have something in the project twice? I looked and can't find anything showing up twice!

Here's a picture of the log:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601404/apple-mach-o-linker-error-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1

Comment: why did you accept the top rated answer if it didn't resolve your issue...?

Comment: @umairqureshi_6's answer is not proper for this question. I can't understand how it can be the accepted answer of this question. It didn't give any hint.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

i was facing same issue today in xcode 8 version 8.3.2

right click on issue --> reveal in log

[image]

then you are able to check what is causing that issue

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that!

Here's what I get in the log: http://imgur.com/vFkNJzZ

Comment: I finally solved this. You helped lead me in the right direction! It really sucked that Xcode didn't reveal the log when clicked on...Could have saved me some time!

Comment: Thanks for the Reveal in Log tip. I didn't know I could use it

Comment: @JakeDobson Can you please tell me how did you solve this?

Comment: @GhasemTabatabaei Check my answer below

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't actually answer the question, only potentially assist in reaching the solution.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 120):

Maybe you installed a *pod file* and you are still trying to build from the `.xcodeproj` file instead of `.xcworkspace`

Comment: No, I used Carthage for that reason. That's a legitimate answer that could help other people with this same error, though!

Comment: I added m$ AppCenter code to an existing project and it needed Pods. No idea what was going on and had been doing it with the `.xcodeproj` for over a year.. Something this simple!

Comment: My fix was somewhat related to this. I had recently upgraded some dependencies and the project now used CocoaPods. Previously I was always working from the project file. I opened the workspace file, which had both my project and Pods in it, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 42):

the only thing that worked for me was to run `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`

Comment: The question has been answered. If you see my comment below, I had imported a file that had already been imported into that file. The project was in a race condition trying to reference the file twice.

Comment: ok yeah it jsut didnt work for me and when i googled it this is what came up, so i thought id try and help someone else...im new to this, should i delete my answer?

Comment: I guess not since it's already there. I'm sure somebody might find it useful. The app I was using did not use cocoapods. The thing is, this error is very common and gives little information about itself. So many solutions can be found, depending on each project.

Comment: It saves my day! God bless you!

Answer (score 22):

did you try a clean? cmd + shift + k

Comment: Oh yeah..plenty of times!

Comment: That's literally all I get...Clicking on the text does not send me to any extra information or the location of the file where it happened like it does for most errors. Nothing in the console, it doesn't ever get to running the app because of this error..

Comment: FWIW, I encountered this issue recently when building with an SDK and @FranciscoPerez's suggestion did the trick. Definitely recommend it as a first step before you get too deep into debugging.

Comment: One of the funny things is, after I try all the suggestion in this whole page, it still cant , but then in last, I in xCode => Product => Clean Build Folder
(means your answer here) , finally its work !!!!!!!!! build succeeded

Answer (score 11):

Okay...So here is what solved my problem...

in App Delegate File:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "DarkSkyAPI.h"
//#import "Credentials.h"
```

I had imported Credentials.h already in the DarkSkyAPI.m file in my project. Commenting out the extra import made the error go away!

Some things to mention and maybe help anyone in the future. @umairqureshi_6's answer did help me along the process, but did not solve it. He led to where I was able to dig out the info. I kept seeing AppDelegate and DarkSkyAPI files showing up in the error log and the information it was pulling from Credentials file was causing the error. I knew it had to be in one of these 3 files, so I immediately checked imports, because I remembered hearing that the .h carries all the imports from its .m file. Boom!

Answer (score 7):

Select the project-> Build Phase->Link Binary with libraries and add all pod libraries.

Comment: Yes! This one solves it in 2023, confirmed and many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I k now the question has already been answered. But if this helps somebody save some time : 
I had the same error. I checked everything to find a very small and stupid mistake from my side. I imported a core data ManagedObject custom file in a view controller of my project. **I accidentally imported the .m file instead of the .h** file which was causing the duplicate symbol in architecture error (linker command failed) because my .m file of properties class imports the .h file of core data class and hence causing duplicate import.

So just check if u have imported the right files before you try multiple solutions.!

Comment: Yes! This was very similar to my problem. I had the same file imported twice in my project. 

Rather, I imported a "fileA.h" into "fileB.h", but then imported "fileA.h" and "fileB.h" into "fileC.h", or something along those lines...So the app crashes because it does not know which to use. 

Definitely a good place to have a reminder for others to double check their file imports!

Answer (score 6):

A lot of solutions are mentioned above. No one worked for me(but please try above first).

Select Project -> Select Target -> Linked Framework and Libraries -> Add all pod libraries . (remove if they exist in embedded binaries)

Now remove these from Framework Folder in left file explorer of xcode.

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using Carthage for dependencies.

Just go to Select Project -> Build Settings -> Search for Enable Bitcode -> If it is selected to Yes, select  No.

That solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the reason of the error is library which was linked two times.

I use `react-native` so it was linked automatically using `react-native link` and manually in xcode.

Comment: can you elaborate pls on the fix?

Comment: @HagaiHarari I don't remember a lot of details. I would try to unlink manually in xcode and check.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem.

The cause was that I declared **same global variable in 2 files**. So it was showing same error saying **2 duplicate symbols**.

The solution was to remove those variables.

Comment: why did you remove both and not just one?

Answer (score 2):

For any one having this issue with Flurry framework. This is what fixed my issue.
For me the issue was that i had imported the following files but never used them.
"libFlurryTVOS_9.2.3"
"libFlurryWatch_9.2.3"

So all I had to do was go to project target settings and remove these 2 files from the "Linked framework and libraries" section and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `Find Implicit Dependencies` checkbox is checked.

(Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Build -> Find Implicit Dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

I was testing the Sparkle framework with CocoaPods.

Sadly, I put `pod 'Sparkle', '~> 1.21'` in the PodFile in the wrong place. I put it underneath Testing (for unit tests).

Once placed in correct spot in PodFile, everything's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do `import Foundation`!

I was using Kitura for Swift server side and kept forgetting this!

Comment: Ha. Yeah, you will always need to at least import Foundation before you do anything! I usually import UIKit instead of Foundation, because almost always I will need to use features of UIKit and UIKit has inherits everything from Foundation for you. Imports with Objc can be pretty tricky, but it looks like you were using Swift?

Comment: Yes I was using Swift, the file at hand wasn't showing any compiler issues, but only during running the file, I ran into this issue!

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it really checks for that until runtime, I could be wrong. But, it seems like it wouldn't have an issue until you were trying to access something from Foundation, couldn't find the import, then couldn't continue the process -- crash!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my problem and solution:

I removed two files from the source code using source tree(Version controller). After applying the diff, that contains the two classes I removed, Xcode didn't add it automatically. So I got linker error.

I manually added the files, by right click on group name and select "Add files to ". Now my error got resolved.

If anyone faced the linker error regarding class file, then try to add it manually.

Comment: It definitely seems like a file issue they are trying to hint at...Files elsewhere are not retrieving information from one another seems commonly found on this page. Thanks for your reply. Hoping it helps someone down the road!

Answer (score 1):

Did not have this problem when I built and ran on my own device. Only had this problem with simulators. I just simply restarted my computer and ran it. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have change the `Target` name in my `Podfile` So it's create the same Error for me.

> Solution

Just go `project-> Build Phase->Link Binary with libraries` Remove the old `FrameWorks` by click on `minus button(-)` And clean and Run again. It's work me.

[image]

Remove Unwanted `.framework`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't work for me so here I share my solution in case it might help somebody else:

My problem was that I was configuring the Podfile of my XCode-Project for the wrong platform. Changing "platform :ios" at the beginning of my Podfile to "platform :macos" worked for me to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

IOS version in build phases of pod(in xcode) and ios version in pod file should be same (Try with 9.0)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you are checking out any github project, then instead of using git clone, use git lfs clone, as sometimes, some large files are not properly cloned by using git only. Also, make sure your bitcode is disabled.

Comment: good note..but usually the console will let you know that some files are too large to be transferred?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the gem lock file was specifying an older version of cocoapods than the one I had installed. I had to re-branch and run `bundle exec pod install` instead of `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is different for most of us, and the error message has decent info. In my case, the Deployment Target was set to `10.13` by the `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13` line, but I was running `10.14`. So I had to switch my Deployment Target to `10.14` in General > Deployment Info, in order for the ITLibrary-related symbols to be available again.

```
cd /Users/foo/src/scrobble/macos/itunes-scrobble
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13

... SNIP ...

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ITLibMediaItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ITLibPlaylist", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ITLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was producing multiple products from the same project. For one of the products, the `main.m` file imported a header file from another folder under the same project. But that file was not included in "Complied Sources" under "Build Phase". This caused a linker error.

After carefully comparing the "Build Phases" settings for a product that could be built successfully, I realized that the `.m` file of the header needs to be included in the list of "Compiled Source". My issue was resolved after adding that file. Attaching a picture for clarity. The highlighted file had to be added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons of this problem might be "Build Active Architecture Only". You need set to true.

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue occurred with xcode 14, some frameworks on pods had minimum deployment target on ios 8.0, to fix the issue I added the following to pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = "12.0"
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by deleting node modules, lock file, Pods, and podfile.lock and reinstall nod modules and pods.

You can hit the below command for simplicity:

- rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf ios/Pods && rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock && yarn && npx pod-install

Answer (score 0):

*MY SOLUTION:
I tried many options, but none of them helped, I started to delete everything from the project and after deleting one script, everything worked for me.
This script was NativeShare.cs
Here is part of code which is potentially broke the project:*

```
#if UNITY_IOS
    public struct ConfigStruct
    {
        public string title;
        public string message;
    }

    [DllImport ("__Internal")] private static extern void showAlertMessage(ref ConfigStruct conf);
    
    public struct SocialSharingStruct
    {
        public string text;
        public string url;
        public string image;
        public string subject;
    }
    
    [DllImport ("__Internal")] private static extern void showSocialSharing(ref SocialSharingStruct conf);
    
    public static void CallSocialShare(string title, string message)
    {
        ConfigStruct conf = new ConfigStruct();
        conf.title  = title;
        conf.message = message;
        showAlertMessage(ref conf);
    }

    public static void CallSocialShareAdvanced(string defaultTxt, string subject, string url, string img)
    {
        SocialSharingStruct conf = new SocialSharingStruct();
        conf.text = defaultTxt; 
        conf.url = url;
        conf.image = img;
        conf.subject = subject;
        
        showSocialSharing(ref conf);
    }
#endif
```

Hope it will help someone

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me is changing all podfiles minimum deployable version to 11.0

You can also do this by adding a script to the bottom of our podfile:

```
    post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
          project.targets.each do |target|
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = 
    '11.0'
               end
          end
       end
    end
```

Answer (score -5):

Ok, I had the same problem just today and started googling it, when I came across this thread. I haven't finished reading the question when the answer struck my mind:
I declared a class with an empty constructor

```
class MyClass{
    MyClass();

    void func_one(){
    // code
    }

    void func_two(){
    // code
    }

    ~MyClass(){
        cout << "Deleting object" << endl;
     }
};
```

Then I thought why not terminating (not sure if I'm correct with word selection here, but who cares) the constructor of my class with curly braces (`{}`). So I did:

```
class MyClass{
    MyClass(){}

    void func_one(){
    // code
    }

    void func_two(){
    // code
    }

    ~MyClass(){
        cout << "Deleting object" << endl;
     }
};
```

The problem eliminated, my code started working perfectly.

I know, the good practice is to investigate the issue and find the real cause, but this worked for me.

Comment: I do not think this is helpful for this thread...It seems like the error is trying to get at a file issue, like importing the same thing in separate files. I find it strange you would get this error, because this is an Objective-C specific error...

Comment: I got this error in C++ too.  The linker error in your case was probably that the linker couldn't find the code for your constructor.  I had a similar error with a function that I renamed but because Xcode 10 wouldn't open the linker log on its own, and I didn't know you could right-click and "reveal in log", I was stumped for a few minutes trying to locate the error.