# How can I deal with this error? (duplicate symbols for architecture arm64)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I faced the problem the duplicate symbols for architecture arm64. I searched the "stackoverflow.com" and I did some ways. But, same situation.

First, I removed all files **Users/dongki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**.

Second, **removed Build Phases -> compile source**. But, this is not good ways to solve my problem.

How can I deal with the error?

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Hi, Check the yellow highlighted location in your xcode.
"F/Users/..../lib".

 It's taking reference from that location. Delete that, clean once, build again.

Comment: what is the minimum required version set to in Xcode?

Comment: @RatneshShukla Thanks a lot~ But, I resolved the problem soon. I wrote the solution by any chance who faced with similar my problem. Project -> Build Settings -> No Common Blocks -> Yes -> No.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr I'm happy to your answer. I solved the problem! Have a nice day~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: See Images]Please try to play with `No Common Blocks`. It works for me in PJSIP integration.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have classes that implement methods with the exact same name. You will need to refactor one of those methods. 
Seems you have a library `HttpDefaultNetworkManager`, which is in all errors. If you have access to it, you can add a prefix to all its methods so not the same names are used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to your answer~!! But, I resolved the problem soon.
I wrote the solution by any chance who faced with similar my problem. Project -> Build Settings -> No Common Blocks -> Yes -> No.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Product -> Clean` and re-run the project.

else `Cmd+Shift+K` to clean the project and run again.

Goto "Build settings" -> Target -> Set "Enable Bitcode" = NO.

If you like to see what exactly making error refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801476/6606820

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I resolved this problem. And my solution wrote the comment above. Thank you!