# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) after pod install in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I want use the **AFNetworking** and **SwiftyJSON** libraries in my project

This is my pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
target 'Kids' do

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

After installing the pod file, I opened the `.xcworkspace`
and added the framework target->linked framework and libraries.
in swift file import the frameworks 
like:

```
import AFNetworking
import SwiftyJSON
```

when I build the project am getting the this error:

> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, first thing to do when getting build errors is delete derived data:

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations

click the grey arrow and remove the folder with your project name.

Also do a clean, Cmd+shift+k

In the past I've had pod errors that got solved by reinstalling the pod file using

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

try removing workspace,podfile.lock and pods folder and re-install pod.