# ld: framework not found MCCMerchant_sandbox

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I am trying to integrate [Master card merchant SDK](http://[]%20https://developer.mastercard.com/page/masterpass-merchant-sdk-for-ios#). I am following all steps as described but always fails with error framework not found.

https://developer.mastercard.com/page/masterpass-merchant-sdk-for-ios#

[image]

Below is the screen shot of my framework search path

[image]

Below is the error which I am getting when trying to add framework in Xcode project

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif

Comment: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/issues/634

Comment: Will need more details , can you show your frameworks and your framework search path in the build settings ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all You need to be sure that framework included in linked libraries. Go to project settings and check it is listed in Link binary With Libraries section. 
[image]