# Fabric.unitypackage into my project. ios xcode build error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, google-fabric

Please refer to my picture.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

mac os : high sierra 10.13.2

xcode : 9.2

unity : 5.6.4p4

Please save my day :(

Comment: Kindly add the errors as text.

Comment: @WaqasBukhary error texts in screenshot1 / screensho2

Comment: If you will not summarize the errors as text in the post then this will not be helpful for the future users who are facing the similar issues. And I will also vote to close this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linker Command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation), Xcode 8, Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif)

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Have you re-added the frameworks in Xcode in addition to the Unity project?