# Can't run app on iPhone 5 iOS 10.3.3

Tags: xcode

When trying to run my app on several iPhone fives I run into this error running Xcode 9.2 on MacOs High Siera 10.13.3

A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/Wunder-2018-01-14-163854.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (_mode == modeFinalAddress), function finalAddress, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ld64/ld64-305/src/ld/ld.hpp, line 759.

See image for more details.[image]

It works fine on other devices. Unfortunately, I don't have another device on iPhone 10.3.3 to test if its iOS 10.3.3 or iPhone 5 that it doesn't want to run with. I'm not sure what other information I can provide that is useful.

Comment: I am having the same issue! But I am not sure how to solve it

Comment: If I find a solution I will post it here but since I can use other devices I'm not actively trying to solve the problem Its unlikely that I will find a solution but hopefully someone does.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif

Comment: Not yet. Will try it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a valid architecture to the Build Settings in the Xcode.

The Correct architecture is `armv6`·

[image]