# Showing Recent Issues clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to IOS app development..I trying to integrate firebase firestore..After doing all add commands..I build using **command+B**  then I am getting below errors...how to solve

**Below is my error**

[image]

**Below is my project structure**

[image]

Comment: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/39247126-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-vto-see-invocation.  I got solution here..but I do not know how to apply

Comment: Try to open project.xcworkspace instead of project.xcodeproj.

Comment: ya but I do not know how to do that....I have this two file `project.xcworkspace`, `project.xcodeproj` but I am not getting how to open as you mention...I new for iOS please help

Comment: Press Command + Q to exit xcode. And open testing_gowtham.xcworkspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open `project.xcworkspace` instead of `project.xcodeproj`.

> **Note:** Press `Command + Q` to exit xcode. And open
>   `yourfile.xcworkspace`.

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and build again solve your problem.

Product - Clean

Then also, if error is still there delete you derived data.

Library/Developer/Xcode/ Derived data

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif @GowthamanM

Comment: thanks bro I will check and update you..wait for sometime plz

Comment: Also try - Delete your pod file and install it again.

Comment: ok I will try above link if it's not working..I will delete pod file...shall I proceed as it's or what is your opinion

Comment: First try delete and install pod file, then proceed with link @GowthamanM