# Unity build with Google's Firebase Firestore returning many errors

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I try to run my Unity-built project in Xcode, I get a large number of errors that look to be related to Firebase's Firestore.  I do not get any errors when running with just Unity for Android on Windows.

I am using Firebase 6.15.2 and I'm trying to compile my iOS app using Xcode v11.6.  The Xcode iOS project was created by Unity 2019.4.4f1 running on Windows.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "firebase::firestore::nanopb::ByteString::ByteString(firebase::firestore::nanopb::ByteString&&)", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::UserDataConverter::ParseScalar(firebase::firestore::FieldValue const&, firebase::firestore::core::ParseContext&&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
  "firebase::firestore::model::ArrayTransform::ArrayTransform(firebase::firestore::model::TransformOperation::Type, std::__1::vector<firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue, std::__1::allocator<firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue> >)", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::UserDataConverter::ParseSentinel(firebase::firestore::FieldValue const&, firebase::firestore::core::ParseContext&&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
  "firebase::firestore::model::ServerTimestampTransform::ServerTimestampTransform()", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::UserDataConverter::ParseSentinel(firebase::firestore::FieldValue const&, firebase::firestore::core::ParseContext&&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
  "firebase::firestore::model::NumericIncrementTransform::NumericIncrementTransform(firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue)", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::UserDataConverter::ParseSentinel(firebase::firestore::FieldValue const&, firebase::firestore::core::ParseContext&&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
  "firebase::firestore::core::ParseContext::ChildContext(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::UserDataConverter::ParseArray(std::__1::vector<firebase::firestore::FieldValue, std::__1::allocator<firebase::firestore::FieldValue> > const&, firebase::firestore::core::ParseContext&&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
      firebase::firestore::UserDataConverter::ParseArrayTransformElements(firebase::firestore::FieldValue const&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
  ...
  "firebase::firestore::util::Comparator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::Compare(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::util::ComparisonResult firebase::firestore::util::CompareContainer<std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&) in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(field_path_8e22025db8fd9ff2d7ac3ddb6af30a3e.o)
      firebase::firestore::util::ComparisonResult firebase::firestore::util::CompareContainer<std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > >(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&) in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
      firebase::firestore::immutable::impl::ArraySortedMap<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue, firebase::firestore::util::Comparator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::insert(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue const&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
      firebase::firestore::immutable::impl::LlrbNode<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue> firebase::firestore::immutable::impl::LlrbNode<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue>::InnerInsert<firebase::firestore::util::Comparator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue const&, firebase::firestore::util::Comparator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > const&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
      firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue std::__1::__lower_bound<firebase::firestore::immutable::impl::ArraySortedMap<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue, firebase::firestore::util::Comparator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >::lower_bound(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const::'lambda'(std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)&, std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue> const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue, firebase::firestore::util::Comparator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
  "_FIRRemoteConfigThrottledEndTimeInSecondsKey", referenced from:
      ____ZN8firebase13remote_config5FetchEy_block_invoke in libFirebaseCppRemoteConfig.a(remote_config_ios_e6d2ed559f32c182ac8412737f5fb36a.o)
      ____ZN8firebase13remote_config8internal20RemoteConfigInternal17EnsureInitializedEv_block_invoke in libFirebaseCppRemoteConfig.a(remote_config_ios_e6d2ed559f32c182ac8412737f5fb36a.o)
      long long firebase::remote_config::internal::FutureCompleteWithError<firebase::SafeFutureHandle<bool>, bool>(NSError*, firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl*, firebase::SafeFutureHandle<bool>, bool) in libFirebaseCppRemoteConfig.a(remote_config_ios_e6d2ed559f32c182ac8412737f5fb36a.o)
      ____ZN8firebase13remote_config8internal20RemoteConfigInternal5FetchEy_block_invoke in libFirebaseCppRemoteConfig.a(remote_config_ios_e6d2ed559f32c182ac8412737f5fb36a.o)
  "firebase::Timestamp::Timestamp(long long, int)", referenced from:
      _Firebase_Firestore_new_TimestampInternal__SWIG_1 in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(firestore_afa9ea7678313e4b91bb158d472a9e2c.o)
      firebase::firestore::UserDataConverter::ParseScalar(firebase::firestore::FieldValue const&, firebase::firestore::core::ParseContext&&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
  "firebase::firestore::GeoPoint::GeoPoint(double, double)", referenced from:
      _Firebase_Firestore_new_GeoPointInternal in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(firestore_afa9ea7678313e4b91bb158d472a9e2c.o)
  "firebase::firestore::api::DocumentSnapshot::CreateReference() const", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::DocumentSnapshotInternal::reference() const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(document_snapshot_ios_430abd732548c2f7bcba1499365c9caa.o)
  "firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue::FieldValue()", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::FieldValue::Null() in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(field_value_b318b937baabea572d056aefd3d9d0de.o)
      std::__1::shared_ptr<firebase::firestore::immutable::impl::FixedArray<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue> > const> std::__1::shared_ptr<firebase::firestore::immutable::impl::FixedArray<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue> > const>::make_shared<>() in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(document_snapshot_ios_430abd732548c2f7bcba1499365c9caa.o)
      firebase::firestore::UserDataConverter::ParseSentinel(firebase::firestore::FieldValue const&, firebase::firestore::core::ParseContext&&) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
      std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, firebase::firestore::model::FieldValue>::pair<true, false>() in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(user_data_converter_ios_c8d050486a942078faf3c42cf8358d9f.o)
  "firebase::firestore::api::Firestore::GetBatch()", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::FirestoreInternal::batch() const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(firestore_ios_eec52dfa6e1434eb3ea69ba309362c0c.o)
  "firebase::auth::Auth::AddAuthStateListener(firebase::auth::AuthStateListener*)", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::FirebaseCppCredentialsProvider::SetCredentialChangeListener(std::__1::function<void (firebase::firestore::auth::User)>) in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(credentials_provider_ios_c4b11a23b793b1dcedea6096ad99afca.o)
  "firebase::firestore::api::Firestore::GetDocument(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::FirestoreInternal::Document(char const*) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(firestore_ios_eec52dfa6e1434eb3ea69ba309362c0c.o)
  "firebase::firestore::core::Transaction::MarkPermanentlyFailed()", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::TransactionInternal::MarkPermanentlyFailed() in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(transaction_ios_23d9210df3e403c5645ebc8e23ae5b28.o)
  "firebase::Timestamp::ToString() const", referenced from:
      _Firebase_Firestore_TimestampInternal_ToString in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(firestore_afa9ea7678313e4b91bb158d472a9e2c.o)
      firebase::firestore::FieldValue::ToString() const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(field_value_b318b937baabea572d056aefd3d9d0de.o)
  "firebase::firestore::GeoPoint::ToString() const", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::FieldValue::ToString() const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(field_value_b318b937baabea572d056aefd3d9d0de.o)
  "firebase::firestore::api::DocumentSnapshot::GetData() const", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::DocumentSnapshotInternal::GetData(firebase::firestore::DocumentSnapshot::ServerTimestampBehavior) const in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(document_snapshot_ios_430abd732548c2f7bcba1499365c9caa.o)
  "firebase::firestore::util::AsyncQueue::Create(std::__1::unique_ptr<firebase::firestore::util::Executor, std::__1::default_delete<firebase::firestore::util::Executor> >)", referenced from:
      firebase::firestore::FirestoreInternal::CreateFirestore(firebase::App*, std::__1::unique_ptr<firebase::firestore::auth::CredentialsProvider, std::__1::default_delete<firebase::firestore::auth::CredentialsProvider> >) in libFirebaseCppFirestore.a(firestore_ios_eec52dfa6e1434eb3ea69ba309362c0c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Showing first 200 notices only
```

In Unity package manager, I can confirm the "Cloud Firestore for Firebase" are version 6.15.2.  However, my Podfile that gets generated looks a bit weird when it says version 1.15.0.  Is this the problem?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '6.24.0'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '4.1.0'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', '1.15.0'
end
```

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051876/10810527) may be relevant, could you check it out?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to be it.  Unity didn't generate an .xcworkspace file and a Build Clean also didn't help.

Comment: Your comment actually does help!  The missing .xcworkspace has pushed me down a rabbit hole and I'm now working on how to resolve that part.  If I get answer, I'll update.

Comment: Awesome! If you're still stuck you can update your question so we can help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, I still haven't got all the kinks but I wanted to post an answer that @Ajordat helped me come to find.  If I run into another issue, I'll update.

I was missing a `.xcworkspace` file which is what I should be opening in XCode to not get the above errors.  To get this missing file, I needed to run `pod install` from a terminal window on my Mac in the project folder.

I haven't found a way to do this part on Windows but it shouldn't be necessary since you need XCode anyway to do the final compile which only runs on Mac.  That being said, I found this in case anyone is interested: [Using CocoaPods on Windows](https://medium.com/@airtdave/using-cocoapods-on-windows-dec471735f51)

Comment: This worked for me as well: the errors specifically occurred when I switched from an Intel mac to an M1. Either moving to a new mac didn't install the Pods (maybe it thought they were already installed), or it's an issue on M1 - not sure which. In either case, downloading cocoapods and running pod install creates a `.xcworkspace` which resolves the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the 1.15.0 version might gear toward Firestore in particular. Just by curiousity, does Unity works with the previous version of Firebase like Firebase 5.3.0?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to leave a comment?  You can read about Unity and Firebase support here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup