# clang Error: Linker Command Failed for Unity in Native

Tags: c#, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

My project is Unity in Native integration, had problem with clang error: Build failed refer image. I had gone through other sources in stack overflow to clear  with clang error. I tried to remove my main.mm file, then build get succeeded but app will crash when calling unity screen. So I have to keep both files AppDelgate and main.mm file. Couldn't fix this....issue. if anyone could please..[image]

Comment: See if there is one or more missing files.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801476/10150796

Comment: Have you tried **disabling the bit code** in build settings?
what are all the **plugins** you are using in your project?

Comment: @Karthi I have disable bitcode in my build settings,, and its fine with other build settings. If I remove main.mm file build get succeeds but unity view doesn't appear. I found the solution from below answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, hope that it's unity in swift native integration.

**NOTE: This solution is only for case: Unity in Native iOS**

From your screen shot it show that you are using 2 main files in Xcode. There are 2 options to fix this out.

**Option 1)** you may keep both files in **Build Phases --> Compile sources** , but in your AppDelegate, command @UIApplicationMain

```
import UIKit
//@UIApplicationMain 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
.......................................}
```

This will build succeeded and unity view appears at initial stage.

**Option 2)** If you want to show unity view with button, Remove your main.mm file from **Build Phases --> Compile sources**, so app won't crash in unity view by using 'shared window appDelegate' and try this code in your AppDelegate (uncommand @UIApplicationMain)

```
 func unityWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        return UnityGetMainWindow()
    }

    func showUnityWindow() {
        unityWindow()?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    func hideUnityWindow() {
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

then, in your View Controller

```
 private var isShowUnityWindow = false
     override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
           isShowUnityWindow = false

        }
         @IBAction func startUnityandHide(_ sender: UIButton)
            {

                isShowUnityWindow = !isShowUnityWindow
                var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

                if isShowUnityWindow {
                    appDelegate?.unityWindow()!.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 200, width: 300, height: 300)
                    appDelegate?.showUnityWindow()
                } else {
                    appDelegate?.hideUnityWindow()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Finally u made it, solved my issue after 10 days!!!>>>..........Cheers buddy ........Your solution works in both options....