# Error with Xamarin Forms iOS release build

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, build, release

I'm developing an app with Xamarin Forms for Android and iOS.

The Android version is in the store and is working fine.

The iOS version however works perfectly in debug mode, but whenever I install the app in release mode on a device, it crashes immediately.

I'm not getting much info when it crashes, but this is what I'm able to log:

```
CallContext.LogicalGetData (System.String )
System.Diagnostics
CorrelationManager.get_ActivityId ()
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ActivityScope
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ActivityScope..ctor (System.Guid activityId) <0x106c6d570 + 0x0002f> in <908f52fa2d71491f9d0af93469cedaec#571c84de367aff99c9a9dd63a567fef4>:0
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos
ClientContextCore.RunWithDiagnosticsHelperAsync[TResult] (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.ITrace trace, System.Func`2[T,TResult] task)
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos
ClientContextCore.OperationHelperWithRootTraceAsync[TResult] (System.String operationName, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.RequestOptions requestOptions, System.Func`2[T,TResult] task, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceComponent traceComponent, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceLevel traceLevel)
*AppName*.Services
LiveDataStoreGameType.GetAll_AzureAsync (System.Boolean forceRefresh, *AppName*.Shared.enCulture culture)
```

Does anyone have any idea what to do or what this is? It's almost as if the app isn't able to download anything (but I know for a fact that it has a connection).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: check the linker behavior(in ios build) to see if it is "don't link" and try again.

Comment: I've tried that, but when I try to build with that setting, I get a "linker command failed" error.
Normally it's on "Link Framework SDKs only"

Comment: It will be easier To troubleshoot your problem  with more detail information such as the whole stack trace or crash log.

Comment: Hi Adrian,
Sorry for the late response...
I can narrow it down to the Azure Cosmos DB package. Everytime I want some data from Azure Cosmos the app doesn't do what it's suppose to. But it is really hard to get more exception data; the app crashes before it can be send. And debugging in release mode doesn't seem to work either.

I did manage to get this error from the app:

CallContext.LogicalGetData (System.String)
System.NotSupportedException: Linked Away

Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: Here is the similar question about linker command failed I think this could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif