# Xcode project giving pod file error for FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework . How to solve it?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm working on a book project and the project is connected by API . I'm working on the book app which has different libraries imported from the various places.

Recently, i cloned the project from bitbucket in Xcode and tried to run it. The result i got i error as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPaul.jpg)

It shows :

```
ld: in /Users/ishinfoservices/Documents/vadltaldhambooks/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRAnalyticsConnector_a8eeba373b74508311b8b22b8d3202a6.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/ishinfoservices/Documents/vadltaldhambooks/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Help needed to fix the error, as the project has lots of mixes of old libraries along with .h and .m files, the swift files with wireframes

Comment: Just go through this. It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the image I saw that you are trying run the app on the iOS simulator, then you could try to add the `arm64` to the `Excluded Architectures` on the Build Settings section of your project or target, it would be like:

[image]

Take in mind that if you use Cocoa Pods is possible that also you should add the `arm64` to the `Exclude Architectures` into the Pods project

After the above, clean, build and run the project on the iOS simulator, is possible that on your physical device you must remove the `arm64` from the `Exclude Architectures`, it could depend on what you use in your project.

On the other hand, you can try the following: Select the project -> Select the target -> Go to the Build Phases -> Expand the Link Binary with libraries and add all pod libraries (remove if they exist in embedded binaries or Remove the old FrameWorks), after that, clean and build the project

Comment: I leave to you a useful link https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/2687252

Comment: The issue remains unsolvable for one specific project. I tried the above method but still not working. Other projects works fine.

Comment: Ah Ok, I edited my answer, you can test the last that I added

Comment: i reset  all the excluded architecture and active architecture. now i can run project on my connected device but not on any iphone simulators