# Linker command failed during iOS build

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a React Native project for iOS after I upgraded React Native Firebase from v10 to v17.
I solved many errors, but I cannot get rid of this last one:

```
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
ld: building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file (/.../ios/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics[arm64][2](CLSBinaryImage.o)) built for 'iOS'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'React-RCTActionSheet' from project 'Pods')
/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'Fabric' from project 'Pods')
/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'React-callinvoker' from project 'Pods')
/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')
/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'RCTRequired' from project 'Pods')
/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'FBLazyVector' from project 'Pods')
/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'React' from project 'Pods')
/.../ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'Crashlytics' from project 'Pods')

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:637201FD-B9E2-4C2E-8797-6DD23CC5440C, OS:17.0, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:637201FD-B9E2-4C2E-8797-6DD23CC5440C, OS:17.0, name:iPhone 11 }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/backporch-gklonbvhvuffcrcrsbundznbgjak/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Backporch.app/Backporch normal (in target 'backporch' from project 'backporch')
(1 failure)
```

I should mention that the Android build works just fine; only the iOS one fails.

Pods file:

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
# use_modular_headers!
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'backporch' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'backporchTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
      end
    end
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
end
```

React Native Version: 0.63.5
React Native Firebase Version: 17.5.0
Xcode Version: 15

Expected the app to be successfully built. I'm stuck on that error though

Comment: I would encourage you to consider using Expo so as to avoid futzing around in the "native bits" as much as possible.  Expo is developer tooling layered on top of React Native.  Expo takes care of 99% of the "upgrade problem" with React-Native, among many other things.

Comment: Click this link to find the answer to your question. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif