# Xcode 15: Facing "linker command failed with exit code 1" issue

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

I am currently using Xcode 15, and I'm encountering the following error during the build process:

I have reviewed my code and project settings, but I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause of this issue. Here are some details about my project:

- Xcode version: 15
- I am using third-party frameworks.
- also if run the unit test case same problems occurred.

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue without success:

- [pods updated, Framework removed and reinstalled,Restart Xcode and Clean Build and Run again.]

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: there is more to the error, pls post the complete error log.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif