# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) xcode 15 react native

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

I am getting this react native error while building my app. I am trying to build my app but getting this error from a week.
I just cloned a new project did pod install and tried to build. i have also done pod install --repo update

[Picture for my xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGcNm.jpg)

I have tried:

-pod install

- delete pods and install again with --repo update

and all possible solutions that are in stackoverflow

Update :

I have updated the detailed error in screenshot [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/fezbZ.png

Comment: provide more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TalhaAkbar I have Updated the error in above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this before. What's happening is [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) is not installed/not working right. This should help you out:

1. `cd ios` to get into your ios folder
2. `bundle install`
3. `bundle exec pod install`

If you run into an error such as `Could not locate Gemfile`, that means you haven't installed Cocoapods yet. You'll want to run `sudo gem install cocoapods` in your ios folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am doing "bundle install"  that in project/ios. It's saying "Could not locate Gemfile". Can you please help me on that?

Comment: That means you're missing cocoapods. You're gonna want to run `sudo gem install cocoapods`. I'll also update my answer

Comment: I did. Still giving me error. Could not locate Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should remove your `DerivedData` with

```
 rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

And then go on

> project -> Build Phase -> Link Binary with libraries and add all pod libraries.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795385/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation-xcode-8-swif) some one also have same issue and got many answers that you can try to resolved that issue.